# Why was Elsie the "Final boss" in TWGOK?

Tags: the-world-god-only-knows

What really confused me was the part where his partner Elsie who was a demon to help catch the evil spirits from the very beginning turned out to be the "final boss" which is how Katsuragi's contract with her ended...

I didn't get it because after he defeated the evil and came back from the past, the contract should have ended since he did everything he needed to already but why was she the final boss, I still don't get it... Can someone please explain to me why and how is Elsie the "final boss"...